# grails.rest.RestfulController. How to add a parameter in the UrlMappings?

Tags: grails, grails-controller

How to add a parameter in the UrlMappings, without overriding the update?

```
    "/hospitalReferral/admission/$id?"(controller:'hospitalReferral'){
        action = [PUT:"update"]
        admissionDate = new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'") //controller does not see this parameter
     }
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's the use of adding a parameter to update if you are not willing to override the method to do something with the parameter?

Comment: To save, since I can not trust the time the workstation is running the browser. It should be borne in mind that the application being developed is a SPA

Comment: Ohh.. I sse.. I never thought about that use-case. Very clever and easy solution. (I used to override update to accomplish the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me with Grails 2.4.2

```
"/hospitalReferral/admission/$id?"(controller: 'hospitalReferral', action: 'update', method: 'PUT') {
    admissionDate = new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
}
```

Comment: How does not works? What it does? I found one problem with this approach, and it is that the closure is evaluated when the applications start, not with every request, so all admission will have the same date and time.

Maybe what you need can not be done with urlMappings. maybe your solution is using filters

Comment: example project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3COHhlYWf-7Z0d3UFo0MkZRaWc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: even if one comment :-(

Comment: Sorry for the late replay, I was very busy. Unfortunately I can not run your example. It requires a Postgres database, and if I fix that, I see others issues that I have not the time to investigate.
Can you provide a example without postgres, intelij files, spring-security, just a minimal example of your code.

Anyway, as I said before, I think you can not solve your problem using UrlMapping. Maybe you can find a solution in a filter.

Comment: The saddest thing that using filters failed to achieve results. What kind database using?

Comment: I did a minimal app that uses UrlMapping to create rows in a RestfulController like yours. I did it using the save method because it was easer to test than update, but the idea should be the same.

Basically, it is your exact same solution, but without dependencies, and for me, it is working.

Maybe you have a conflict with a dependency?
https://github.com/fniwes/urlmapping-restful-parameter-example

First try the solution, if it works, add one by one your changes to see which one is interfering. (if any)

Comment: I try to create a new project by means of Grails

Comment: Fernando, what OS you use?

Comment: That example was made with OS X Yosemite (10.10.3)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arbitrary parameters from url mapping.

Example taken from [documentation (Arbitrary Variables)](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#urlmappings) :

```
"/holiday/win" {
     id = "Marrakech"
     year = 2007
}
```

You can access the parameters from controller using `params`.

You can pass number or string but not object. So you need to convert the date into string in order to pass as parameters.

Comment: In the case grails.rest.RestfulController, your example does not work